# Add Load test in visual studio team services

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a web app and Test project, to which I have added Load test combining different scenarios including Coded Web Performance Test.

However How do I deploy these Load tests to visual studio online "Test" tab so that I can run load test from interface

I have CI for my Web APP and unit tests are executed on build but how do Load tests in visual studio get deployed?